# Flot returns incorrect x value (mm/dd/yy - date) after zoom for stack bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, zooming, flot

### I want to get the correct x axis label when user zooms the chart and click on a specific bar

when clicking on the bar on (02/14/14 - xaxis) the alert shows the (02/19/14 - xaxis) label.
It returns the correct date when the zoom(selection) is not firing. but after zooming the chart and clicking on the bar it populate a wrong date.

I am new to flot charts. please help me. thanks.

```
[<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flot Stack Zoom Click</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="plot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--\[if lte IE 8\]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.min.js"></script><!\[endif\]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.valuelabels.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.selection.js"></script>
        
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
    
    var dataset = \[{
        data: \[
            \[1391279400000, -588\],\[1391365800000, -1324\],\[1391452200000, -1525\],\[1391538600000, -588\],\[1391625000000, -1525\],\[1391711400000, -588\],
            \[1391797800000, -1324\],\[1391884200000, -1525\],\[1391970600000, -588\],\[1392057000000, -1234\],\[1392143400000, -588\],\[1392229800000, -1324\],
            \[1392316200000, -1525\],\[1392402600000, -588\],\[1392489000000, -1525\],\[1392575400000, -588\],\[1392661800000, -1324\],\[1392748200000, -1525\],
            \[1392834600000, -588\]
        \],
        color:'#9D538E',
        label: "Out"
    },
    {
        data: \[
            \[1391279400000, 3221\],\[1391365800000, 2496\],\[1391452200000, 1050\],\[1391538600000, 3221\],\[1391625000000, 1050\],\[1391711400000, 3221\],
            \[1391797800000, 2496\],\[1391884200000, 1050\],\[1391970600000, 2221\],\[1392057000000, 1050\],\[1392143400000, 3221\],\[1392229800000, 2496\],
            \[1392316200000, 1050\],\[1392402600000, 3221\],\[1392489000000, 1050\],\[1392575400000, 3221\],\[1392661800000, 2496\],\[1392748200000, 1050\],
            \[1392834600000, 2221\]
        \],
        color:'#702BD7',
        label: "Intake"
    }, {
        data: \[
            \[1391279400000, 1000\],\[1391365800000, -1000\],\[1391452200000, -475\],\[1391538600000, 1000\],\[1391625000000, -475\],\[1391711400000, 1000\],
            \[1391797800000, -1000\],\[1391884200000, -475\],\[1391970600000, 1000\],\[1392057000000, -475\],\[1392143400000, 1000\],\[1392229800000, -1000\],
            \[1392316200000, -475\],\[1392402600000, 1000\],\[1392489000000, -475\],\[1392575400000, 1000\],\[1392661800000, -1000\],\[1392748200000, -475\],
            \[1392834600000, 1000\]
        \],
        color:'#2082F2',
        label: "Net"
    }\];    
    
            var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", dataset, {
                xaxis: {
                        mode: 'time',
                        timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
                        tickSize: \[1, "day"\], 
                }, 
                series: {
                        bars: {
                            fill: 1,
                            show: true,     
                            barWidth: 100*100*4000,
                        },
                        valueLabels: { 
                            show: true,
                            showAsHtml: true,                   
                        },                  
                }, 
                grid: {
                        hoverable: true,
                        clickable: true,
                        borderWidth: 2,       
                        markings: \[ { yaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#fff" }\],
                        backgroundColor: { colors: \["#000000", "#000000"\] }
                }               
            });
            
            var overview = $.plot("#overview", dataset, {
                xaxis: {
                        mode: 'time',   
                        ticks: \[\]             
                }, 
                yaxis: {
                        ticks: \[\],
                },
                series: {
                        bars: {
                            fill: 1,
                            show: true,                     
                        },              
                }, 
                grid: {
                        markings: \[ { yaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#fff" }\],
                        backgroundColor: { colors: \["#000000", "#000000"\] }
                },
                selection: {
                        mode: "x"
                },
                legend: {show: false}
            }); 
        
                // now connect the two
                $("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {

                        //Reset Chart resolution dropdown
                        $(".chartResolution").val("0");

                               
                        // do the zooming
                        plot = $.plot("#placeholder", dataset, {
                            xaxis: {
                                mode: 'time',       
                                min: ranges.xaxis.from,
                                max: ranges.xaxis.to,
                            }, 
                            series: {
                                bars: {
                                    fill: 1,
                                    show: true,                     
                                    barWidth: 100*100*4000,
                                },
                                valueLabels: { 
                                    show: true,
                                    showAsHtml: true,                   
                                },                  
                            }, 
                            grid: {
                                hoverable: true,
                                clickable: true,
                                borderWidth: 2,       
                                markings: \[ { yaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#fff" }\],
                                backgroundColor: { colors: \["#000000", "#000000"\] }
                            }
                        });

                        
                        // don't fire event on the overview to prevent eternal loop
                        //overview.setSelection(ranges, true);
                        
                });

 

                //bind the plotselected function

                $("#overview").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {          
                                plot.setSelection(ranges);
                });

        $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
            if (item) {
                var tickClicked = item.series.xaxis.ticks\[item.dataIndex+1\].label;         
                alert(tickClicked);
            }
        });
        
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#222222; color:white;">

    <div id="content">
        <div class="demo-container" style="margin-top:1%;">
            <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
            <p class="notifyMessage">Please click and drag and select a range to zoom <a href="#" title="Revert to all data" class="buttonCommon revertToAll">Revert to all data</a></p>
            <div id="overview" class="psycho" style="width:950px;height:150px;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
var tickClicked = item.series.xaxis.ticks[item.dataIndex+1].label;
```

When your plot is unzoomed you have one tick per datapoint (bar).  When you zoom, however, you end up with in between ticks, so the finding a tick by `item.dataIndex` isn't going to work.

I'm guessing you care more about the data associated to the bar (and not really the tick) so  get the bar x value and format it back to a date string.

```
var tickClicked = $.plot.formatDate(new Date(item.datapoint[0]),"%m/%d/%Y");
```

**EDITS**

Instead of making another `.plot` call on zoom redraw the chart with (this is how I do it in my applications using flot):

```
var opts = plot.getOptions();
opts.xaxes[0].min = ranges.xaxis.from;
opts.xaxes[0].max = ranges.xaxis.to;
opts.yaxes[0].min = ranges.yaxis.from;
opts.yaxes[0].max = ranges.yaxis.to;
plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```

Comment: thanks it really worked. Also after zooming Im reverting back to the default view by setting xaxis min and max null. Then after I click on a bar the plotclick function will fire multiple times depending on the resolutions I select. Do you have any idea to prevent this? 

`$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {

if (item) {

if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {

previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

tickClicked = $.plot.formatDate(new

Date(item.datapoint[0]),"%m/%d/%Y");

alert(tickClicked);

ioResizeChart();

}else {previousPoint = null;}

}

});`

Comment: @ThisalAbeysooriya, make sure you are not doing this `$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick"` more than once.  Click bindings are cumulative, so if you rebind to the placeholder, the event will fire for each binding.

Comment: I have **only used one** $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick". When I adjust the chart(Resolution:1 week, 1 month, 1 day, All) I think the chart will redraw overlays over and over again. Is it because of that? thanks.

Comment: @ThisalAbeysooriya, see edit above, it's something to try to see if it prevents your multiple event problem.  It redraws chart instead of re-creating it time and time again.