# Flot chart valueLabels disappears

Tags: jquery, flot

### Some value labels get disappeared when chart has same values for different x-axises

When the chart receives same values for multiple xaxis the valueLabels get disappeared. I have entered the same values for "Out" X axises. Please help me to find a way to prevent disappearing the values from chart.

[CLICK HERE FOR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UYmD.png)

```
var dataset = [{
    data: [
        [1391279400000, -1525],
        [1391365800000, -1525],
        [1391452200000, -1525],
        [1391538600000, -1525],
        [1391625000000, -1525],
        [1391711400000, -1525],
        [1391797800000, -1525],
        [1391884200000, -1525],
        [1391970600000, -1525],         
        [1392057000000, -1525],
        [1392143400000, -1525],
        [1392229800000, -1525],
        [1392316200000, -1525],
        [1392402600000, -1525],
        [1392489000000, -1525],
        [1392575400000, -1525],
        [1392661800000, -1525],
        [1392748200000, -1525],
        [1392834600000, -1525]
    ],
    color:'#9D538E',
    label: "Out"
},
{
    data: [
        [1391279400000, 3221],
        [1391365800000, 2496],
        [1391452200000, 1050],
        [1391538600000, 3221],
        [1391625000000, 1050],
        [1391711400000, 3221],
        [1391797800000, 2496],
        [1391884200000, 1050],
        [1391970600000, 2221],      
        [1392057000000, 1050],
        [1392143400000, 3221],
        [1392229800000, 2496],
        [1392316200000, 1050],
        [1392402600000, 3221],
        [1392489000000, 1050],
        [1392575400000, 3221],
        [1392661800000, 2496],
        [1392748200000, 1050],
        [1392834600000, 2221]
    ],
    color:'#702BD7',
    label: "Intake"
}, {
    data: [
        [1391279400000, 1000],
        [1391365800000, -1000],
        [1391452200000, -475],
        [1391538600000, 1000],
        [1391625000000, -475],
        [1391711400000, 1000],
        [1391797800000, -1000],
        [1391884200000, -475],
        [1391970600000, 1000],          
        [1392057000000, -475],
        [1392143400000, 1000],
        [1392229800000, -1000],
        [1392316200000, -475],
        [1392402600000, 1000],
        [1392489000000, -475],
        [1392575400000, 1000],
        [1392661800000, -1000],
        [1392748200000, -475],
        [1392834600000, 1000]
    ],
    color:'#2082F2',
    label: "Net"
}];

$.plot("#placeholder", dataset, {
    xaxis: {
        mode: 'time',   
        timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
        tickSize: [1, "day"],   
        min: ranges.xaxis.from,
        max: ranges.xaxis.to,
    }, 
    series: {
        bars: {
            fill: 1,
            show: true,                     
            barWidth: 100*100*4000,
        },
        valueLabels: { 
            show: true,
            showAsHtml: true,                   
        },                  
    }, 
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        borderWidth: 2,       
        markings: [ { yaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#fff" }],
        backgroundColor: { colors: ["#000000", "#000000"] }
    }
});
```

---

[image]

> The above mentioned hack is not working. Still the issue appears.
>   1st bar NET - 40
>   2nd  bar NET - 400
>   3rd  bar NET - 450
>   4th  bar NET - 450
>   5th  bar NET - 450
>   6th  bar NET - 750
>   7th  bar NET - 150
>   8th  bar NET - 250
>   The 3rd, 4th and 5th bar "NET" value contains 450. But only 5th bar appears the value label. I have attached the json below. Thanks.

```
{
        "observations": {
            "chartName": "bar",
            "awareBarChartData": [{
                "data": [
                    [1393612200000, "-4500"],
                    [1393698600000, "-2500"],
                    [1393785000000, "-900"],
                    [1394044200000, "-550"],
                    [1393266600000, "-9000"],
                    [1393353000000, "-1500"],
                    [1393439400000, "-4500"],
                    [1393525800000, "-4500"]
                ],
                "label": "OUT",
                "color": "#9D538E"
            }, {
                "data": [
                    [1393612200000, "1300"],
                    [1393698600000, "1000"],
                    [1393785000000, "875"],
                    [1394044200000, "650"],
                    [1393266600000, "4950"],
                    [1393353000000, "950"],
                    [1393439400000, "1300"],
                    [1393525800000, "1300"]
                ],
                "label": "INTAKE",
                "color": "#702BD7"
            }, {
                "data": [
                    [1393612200000, "450"],
                    [1393698600000, "750"],
                    [1393785000000, "150"],
                    [1394044200000, "250"],
                    [1393266600000, "40"],
                    [1393353000000, "400"],
                    [1393439400000, "450"],
                    [1393525800000, "450"]
                ],
                "label": "NET",
                "color": "#2082F2"
            }],![enter image description here][2]
            "id": null,
            "voided": false,
            "uuid": "5f647bdb-dd22-49c1-a742-6dc3aa82abe8"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Without code, it is hard to help.

Comment: For the full code click below link. thanks. [Full CODE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178201/flot-returns-incorrect-x-value-mm-dd-yy-date-after-zoom-for-stack-bar-chart/22180100#22180100)

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [source of the plugin](https://github.com/leonardoeloy/flot-valuelabels/blob/master/jquery.flot.valuelabels.js) (line 82), there's this:

```
val = "" + val;
val = labelFormatter(val);

if (val != last_val || i == series.data.length - 1) {

    <snip>
    last_val = val;
```

So, it appears the author of the plugin is purposely skipping repeating values (there's no comment as to why).

So, you have 3 options, 1.) change the source code of the plugin, 2.) abandon the plugin and label things yourself or 3.) hack in a fix like this:

```
valueLabels: { 
     show: true,
     showAsHtml: true,  
     labelFormatter:  function(v) {
         if (v == this.lastVal){ // if the last value is the same as this one
             v += ' ';  // make in unique
         }
         this.lastVal = v; // remember last value
         return v;
     }
},
```

This will keep the state of the last value and pad it with spaces to ensure it's different as the plugin loops through the values.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the latest version of the valueLabels plugin for this now called 'hideSame'.  Setting it to false will show repeating values.

```
{
    hideSame: false
}
```